# Using ST_Intersects with ST_MakePoint with no SET_SRID

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using `WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2)::geography, 4326), geog)` to find a point within a `geography` field (named `geog` in the example query).

For reasons I can't quite figure out*, `ST_SetSRID` sometimes causes issues, removing it from the query makes these issues go away. I'd like to remove `ST_SetSRID` from the query but can't find anywhere that explains what SRID `ST_Intersects` will use.

`geog` has an SRID of 4326. Will `ST_Intersects` just use that or is going to assume no coordinate system and give me results that differ than when using `ST_SetSRID`?

---

* *In case you are curious the issue has something to do with prepared transactions, nodejs, and the minimum connection pool. For 1 minimum connections in the pool, after 4-6 queries the next query will take 15-30 seconds (which usually takes about 100ms). For 2 min connections it takes about 8-10 queries before issues occur, for 5 min, about 25 queries (and so on). I feel like I'm taking Crazy Pills.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) returns a `geometry`, not a `geography`. You generally don't need to set the SRID for `geography`, since it assumes a default of 4326, so I suggest not using it (unless you have a different ellipsoid or something). (But if you are working with `geometry`, ST_SRID is mandatory).

Furthermore, [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) implicitly operates on either `geometry` or `geography` types. Depending if you used ST_SetSRID or not, it will pick either:

- `ST_Intersects(geometry, geometry)`; or
- `ST_Intersects(geography, geography)`

You can explicitly choose the one of the operators by casting each parameter:

```
ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326)::geography, geog::geography)
```

(note I've moved the first `::geography` to outside ST_SetSRID, so it sets an SRID then casts it as a `geography`). Or equivalently:

```
ST_Intersects(ST_MakePoint($1, $2)::geography, geog::geography)
```

As for the actual performance of the two intersects spatial operators, this depends if you have an index on either `geometry` or `geography` types for `geog`.

Comment: Awesome. I was hoping this was the case. I'm always using geography with an srid of 4326 so this should work perfectly.